# jquery not adding class when using eq()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having a bit of trouble when using this:

```
$('.instrumentSelect').click(function(){
    var thisElement = $(this).index();
    $('.instrumentSelect').eq(thisElement).addClass('active');
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
});
```

removes class just fine, I console logged `var thisElement` and returns the correct index, just not appending the class to it. Fire bug does not return an error.

Comment: your are adding a class active and right next line your are removing it... what actaully you are trying to do ??

Comment: @bipen -- Probably just need to switch those two lines.

Comment: have several dom elements with class of .instrumentSelect, only one at all times will have .active on it. When you click on one of the .instrumentSelect elements, I want the current .active removed, then added to the one that was clicked

Comment: holy crap @bipen that worked. i'm an idiot.

Comment: @user2287474 - Happens to us all once in a while. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but removing the class first and adding it later makes more sense. Also, why are you using `index` and `eq()` when you can add a class with `$(this)`?

Try this:

```
$('.instrumentSelect').click(function(){
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');

});
```

Comment: I originally had this... just backwards lol, that's why i added the eq() assuming it had to be more specific. It's giving me 5 minutes until i can accept the answer. Thanks so much for helping me.

Comment: Just for the record, calling `$('.instrumentSelect')` inside the event handler has a slightly subtle effect. If additional `.instrumentSelect` elements are added to the page after the handler is bound, it won't be bound to the new ones. However, `$('.instrumentSelect')` will grab the entire set, including unclickable elements. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/z845Y/

Comment: Fortunately, `.index()` is smart enough to find the current index of `$(this)`, so it should still work. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MVhbD/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.instrumentSelect').click(function(){
    var thisElement = $(this).index();
    $('.instrumentSelect').eq(thisElement).addClass('active');
    $('.active').not($(this)).removeClass('active');
});
```

or more simply you invert those lines like this

```
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.instrumentSelect').eq(thisElement).addClass('active');
```

You are adding it and then removing it. You have to exclude the object you are manipulating.

Comment: No need to do that, just swap the last two lines.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I don't know how the hell I missed something as simple as the order.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you're trying to clear `.active` class before adding it to current item

```
$('.active').removeClass('active');  
$('.instrumentSelect').eq(thisElement).addClass('active');
```